# Using fields of referenced node as filters in views

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types location & business. Business type has an entity reference field address which is referencing location.
Now I want to use fields of location content type as filters in views to display some business nodes. I have tried relationships & contextual filters but no result appears. Can anyone help ?

EDIT(adding more details):  Actually i want to create a search page displaying list of business nodes. But i want to give an additional exposed filter to user for changing the city. City field is part of location content type. Location & Business content type are related using entity reference as explained above. So how can i use this city field as filter in views. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. You should be more specific to your question to get help.

Comment: IS this what you are trying to do: https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004

Comment: @Triof: i tried this before.. i am able to include fields of referenced node as exposed filters but they are not working when selected.